# Laravel 5.4 GIF Images are saved "statically"

Tags: php, image, laravel, image-processing, laravel-5

I am working on this [Laravel 5.4 Social Network Script](https://codecanyon.net/item/socialite-laravel-social-network-script/) and when I post something the avatar is being displayed "animated" but when it is being saved it is converted to an static image.

I have this in the controller TimelineController@createPost:

```
...
use App\Media;
use App\Post;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
...
public function createPost(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $post = Post::create($input);
    ...
    if ($request->file('post_images_upload_modified')) {
        foreach ($request->file('post_images_upload_modified') as $postImage) {
            $strippedName = str_replace(' ', '', $postImage->getClientOriginalName());
            $photoName = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s').$strippedName;

            $avatar = Image::make($postImage->getRealPath());
            $avatar->save(storage_path().'/uploads/users/gallery/'.$photoName, 60);

            $media = Media::create([
                  'title'  => $photoName,
                  'type'   => 'image',
                  'source' => $photoName,
                ]);

            $post->images()->attach($media);
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

It uses [GD Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to process the images internally.

The file Image.php on [/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/](https://github.com/Intervention/image):

> - @method \Intervention\Image\Image make(mixed $source)                                                                                                                  Universal factory method to create a new image instance from source, which can be a filepath, a GD image resource, an Imagick object or a binary image data.

```
/**
 * Starts encoding of current image
 *
 * @param  string  $format
 * @param  integer $quality
 * @return \Intervention\Image\Image
 */
public function encode($format = null, $quality = 90)
{
    return $this->driver->encode($this, $format, $quality);
}

/**
 * Saves encoded image in filesystem
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  integer $quality
 * @return \Intervention\Image\Image
 */
public function save($path = null, $quality = null)
{
    $path = is_null($path) ? $this->basePath() : $path;

    if (is_null($path)) {
        throw new Exception\NotWritableException(
            "Can't write to undefined path."
        );
    }

    $data = $this->encode(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $quality);
    $saved = @file_put_contents($path, $data);

    if ($saved === false) {
        throw new Exception\NotWritableException(
            "Can't write image data to path ({$path})"
        );
    }

    // set new file info
    $this->setFileInfoFromPath($path);

    return $this;
}
```

The stored image is a GIF but resized despite it is not specified:

[image]

Do you know how to make the image animated when saved?

Comment: https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/176

Comment: @azeós, thanks for replying, I get I can't with that, but would you recommend a solution? I can't use "Imagick" since is not supported by "the PHP installation"

Comment: https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/176#issuecomment-58863939 that could be a solution. If the file is a GIF don't use the `save` method.

Comment: okay then, I will try and get back, post it as an answer.